# How to handle suggested edit removing a link to porn

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam

I just came across a suggested edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827131/how-to-manage-security-with-google-guice/2058962#2058962) which was to remove a link to a porn site.

Removing the link is obviously warranted, but approving it would not address the issue with the answer, which also should be removed.

As it was, I skipped the review and flagged it for moderator attention.

Was this the correct course of action? And should I have flagged it as spam (I was not sure what would have then happened had other users approved the edit) rather than moderator attention?

Comment: I'd like to assume that the link wasn't *always* to a porn site and the link simply died and got replaced to that effect, so spam wouldn't have been the most appropriate flag.

Comment: @BoltClock, That's what I assumed might have been the case as well. I looked at some of the other answers by that user, and they were all good (and nothing to suggest that they were spamming)

Comment: The Internet is really really great...

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention seems appropriate to me.  If you are sure there's a problem but aren't sure how to deal with it, flagging for moderator attention with an explanation is usually a good way to deal with the problem.

Comment: Is there a canonical meta post about link-only answers? This example should definitely be mentioned there!

Comment: It's possible to get the original post from [the web archive](http://web.archive.org), although it seems a bit long to just post into the answer, not to mention that the answer's already deleted and the question's closed.

Comment: Hypothesis: events like this are not intentional. It's undefined behaviour: when the URL dies, it gets set to a random point on the internet. And as we all know, random points on the internet are almost certainly porn. ;)

Comment: Might be worth to write a quick query to see if there are other posts that link to the (now) porn site.

Comment: "_And as we all know, random points on the internet are almost certainly porn_" And that, m'lud, concludes my defence.

Comment: Also an excellent example of why not to consider link-only answers as real answers.  On the internet as X approaches infinity, all links approach porn links.  It's just a matter of time.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, you did the right thing. Moderators act as "exception handlers" in that they handle nonstandard cases that need some case-specific consideration and action to resolve.

Judging by the link's URL and the fact that it was added 7 years ago, it most probably wasn't intended to be spam (i.e. the author is most likely not to blame). At least, enough time has passed (and enough upvotes accumulated as additional evidence) to give them the benefit of the doubt. So it shouldn't have been flagged as spam directly.

Though in this particular case, the answer could be voted to be deleted/very low quality as a link-only answer (regardless or whether the link has died or not), I can only commend you for going the extra mile to have this sorted out the best way possible.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth. Well, other than the second paragraph given my comment on the question anyway.

Comment: "_enough upvotes accumulated_" maybe it was a link to good porn ..?

Comment: @Teemu No porn belongs on a programming site.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I initially read your comment as "No, porn belongs on a programming site."

Comment: @wizzwizz4 don't tell me how to use my votes

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I find poor question on the main site much more as nuisance, than occasional porn links. This was the second one during the five and a half years I've been a member at SO.

Comment: @Teemu Poor questions on the main site can't get you fired from work if you accidentally click on them.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I agree with [ivan's post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356340) for the specific case where the answer under review is link-only.

However, as an alternative, you *could*, if you felt like spending some extra time and the question/answer pair seemed worthwhile, check if the original page can be found at the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180312041604/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356334/how-to-handle-suggested-edit-removing-a-link-to-porn/364467#364467), and update the answer with the essential parts and the archived link.

For the case of an answer which is **not** link-only, I would recommend checking to see if the link has been archived, and if it has been, "Reject and Edit" the suggested edit and replace the link. Otherwise, use "Improve Edit" to dequeue the edit. (You can *always* find something more to "fix" ;) ) Both these options force an edit through so the porn link doesn't hang around waiting for review, or worse still, end up being rejected.

Not sure if "Improve Edit" is more appropriate than "Reject and Edit" if the link has been archived. The advantage of rejecting is that it gives automatic feedback to the suggester, so that they can be "encouraged" to repair the links (by "punishing" them with the denial of the reputation reward). Improving, on the other hand, is silent, but doesn't punish the suggester for attempting to remove porn.

I suppose you *could* post a comment on the answer, @replying to the suggester, suggesting they try repairing the link next time. Probably best overall to just treat it like any other suggested edit and reject/improve depending on what other issues weren't fixed. The only difference being to "force" an edit through.